# SELECT from table returning one set of value but ignoring secondary condition

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that checks the availability of rooms on my database. It needs to accomplish the following:

1) Check **ts_roompref**, **ts_room** and **ts_request** to see if the room is booked

- If the room is not booked at all then the **day_id** and **period_id** in ts_request will not be found when the **ts_room_pref.request_id** is checked in **ts_roompref** and compared to **ts_request.id**.
- In a case where a room entry cannot be found (i.e. it has not been requested) then the room is free

2) If a **day_id** and **period_id** value are found after comparing **ts_request** and **ts_roompref** then it means that we need to look up the **ts_allocation** table to check the status of the room

- If the request status is "Pending,Failed,Declined" then it means that the room has not been allocated yet and is still available
- But if any request status = anything else then it means that the room has been allocated.

I've been struggling for a few hours trying to implement this logic. This is what I've done so far that works:

```
select 1- count(distinct rp.Id) from 
ts_roompref rp, ts_request rq
where rp.room_id= "D.0.02" AND rq.id = rp.request_id
AND day_id like "1" AND period_id like "1";
```

The above code does not take into consideration that the fact may be Pending, Allocated or Declined. It simply assumes that the room is booked if the request_id can be found. How can I improve it to check the request status (if necessary)?

Here is my SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1021/48

Answer (score 0):

There should be percentage signs near "LIKE" conditions in your query

```
... day_id LIKE "%1%" AND period_id LIKE "%1%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @m3sh any idea of how to implement the conditions listed in my question?

Comment: Is there a reason for subtracting the count from 1?

Comment: By the way, don't do "like" thing with integer columns. Just simply check whether it is equal or not.

Comment: Here is some piece of sql to use status condition.
`SELECT ts_room.*, ts_roompref.* ,ts_request.*, ts_allocation.*
FROM ts_room
INNER JOIN ts_roompref ON ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id
INNER JOIN ts_request ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.id
INNER JOIN ts_allocation ON ts_request.id = ts_allocation.request_id
WHERE 
   ts_allocation.status = 'Pending'
    AND
   ts_request.day_id = 2;`
All the columns are included, you may choose the ones you need.